# Imported csv file in R- numeric values read as characters

Tags: r, csv, character

I have opened a CSV file in R studio, and i want create a histogram . But all the numerals are  stored as "Characters" . PFB for the Code :

```
**torque=read.csv("torque.csv",header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
torque <-c("torque.csv")
hist(torque,main =("Histogram of torque"))**
```

I was getting the Error:

> Error in hist.default(torque, main = ("Histogram of torque")) : 'x' must be numeric.**

Later I found that all the numers are stored as "Characters". 
I found this when I used -- class("torque.csv")
how can I fix this. I used as.numeric, but couldn't fix the issue. Please help me on this.

### data

```
Enginetorq
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
52
10
0
0
0
0
0
52
52
52
```

Comment: Hi welcome to stackexchange. It seems you are new to R programming I would recommend you to try this http://tryr.codeschool.com/ to learn the basics in R. Not too long ago I dont even heard about R and even now I dont know much about R.R have a very steep learning curve and cut copying codes without understandng it will never work.

Answer (score 3):

This reads the data into an object called `torque`:

```
torque=read.csv("torque.csv",header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

This then **overwrites** that object so it now stores a single string, "torque.csv", the name of the file:

```
torque <-c("torque.csv")
```

Why do you do that? You've now lost your data in R. So then...

```
hist(torque,main =("Histogram of torque"))
```

...complains because you are trying to do a histogram of the character string "torque.csv".

It should be as simple as:

```
torque=read.csv("torque.csv",header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
hist(torque$Enginetorq,main ="Histogram of torque")
```

ie read in the CSV, and histogram a named column.

Comment: why the parentheses around the `main` argument ... ? (nevermind, I see you're just copying the OP)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `colClasses` subfunction in `read.csv`. It goes as

```
torque=read.csv("torque.csv",header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE, colClasses = c("Enginetorq" = "numeric"))
```

Here is a link http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-colclasses-to-load-data-more-quickly-in-r/ and works for `read.csv` not just `read.table`.

Comment: :) I'm completely new to programming. Thanks a lot Guys!! It worked.

Comment: I have one more doubt, how to plot a barplot or histogram I want plot a histogram of Fuel rate vs Time

ET_ES_FR=read.csv("ET_ES_FR.csv",header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
plot(ET_ES_FR$Eng_fuel_rate, names.arg=ET_ES_FR$Time,ylab = "Fuel Rate",type="l",xlab = "Time") 

Engine_speed,Engine_torq,Eng_fuel_rate,Acc_pedal,Time
650,11,1.15,0,0.000000000000000
650,11,1.2,0,0.000001157408406
650,11,1.2,0,0.000002314816811
651,11,1.2,0,0.000003472225217
651,11,1.2,0,0.000004629633622
651,11,1.2,0,0.000005810186849
650.5,11,1.2,0,0.000006944443157 

Total no.of rows in table: 8241